# How to merge multiple strings in errorformat?

Tags: errorformat

Suppose a source code interpreter outputs the error messages in the following format:

```
M123 Warning path/to/file 123 Description message
```

That is:

```
error_code error_type file line_number message
```

How can I set `errorformat` such that I get both the error_code and message in the quickfix window?
Please note that error_type can be any string, with and without numbers.

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not think this is possible. The message is parsed with `%m`, and this can only be used once. I hope I am wrong, though!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with `errorformat` alone, but there are a couple of ways to do it. One is to filter the output of your interpreter with another program like this:

```
:set mp=make\ \\\|&\ error_filter
```

as explained in an un-indexed paragraph in the reference manual. To find it, execute `:help quickfix-directory-stack` and scroll up to the previous section titled "Filtering messages".

Another way is to post-process the contents of the quickfix list as described under `:help QuickFixCmdPost-example`.

Using either method, edit the error message to put `error_code` next to `message` and use an `errorformat` that sees them together as just a message (`%m`).