# Multiline errorformat

Tags: filetype-tex, errorformat

I would like to parse the latex log to extract warnings from the refcheck package. These warnings look like this

```
Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `eq:my_equation_label' on input line 2
28.
```

The linebreak always appears after a given number of characters, and here it happens to break the line number. I have been trying to set up a working `errorformat` for a couple of hours but this was to no avail. Any idea how I could extract the correct error message and line number?

Comment: I'm not an expert of `errorFormat` but I think if you shared what you have done so far, maybe it could be easier for other users to point out what doesn't work with your expression.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Afaik `'efm'` of vim cannot handle this situation, i.e. `%l` matches only a sequence of digits with no spaces or linebreaks between the digits. Vim help discusses in more detail a possible value of`'efm'` for LaTeX but does not answer this question:

[`:help errorformat-LaTeX`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#errorformat-LaTeX)

Maybe you can ask this on the [issue tracker of vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/issues) or the [vim_dev mailing list](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/vim_dev) to get an official confirmation of this and possibly add a note to the vim help section.

However, there are two ways to handle it anyway:

1. **Change the line length of the log output** of `pdflatex` to a high value. For example, set `makeprg` in vim as following:

   ```
   :set makeprg=max_print_line=10000\ pdflatex\ %
   ```

   Also the plugin [vimtex](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/b3700fedac319b8ada377317a6ba0904b7c526fc/autoload/vimtex/compiler/latexmk.vim#L152-L161) does this for the default compilation method with `latexmk` and would show you also the message by default.
2. **Post-process the log file** with an external tool, e.g. `rubber-info` correctly parses the splitted line number. [The principle idea is](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5057/1292)

   ```
   :set mp=pdflatex\ %\ \\\|&\ error_filter
   ```

   For LaTeX log files quite a few tools exist. Following two are pre-installed under TeXLive 2018

   - [texloganalyser](https://ctan.org/pkg/texloganalyser)
   - [texfot](https://ctan.org/pkg/texfot)

   However, both struggle with the linebreak in the line number and report the wrong line number.

   I have tried following further tools

   - [pplatex](https://github.com/stefanhepp/pplatex) gets the line number correct but does not capture the full message. The warning

     ```
     Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `eq:your_equation_label' on input line 1
     7.
     ```

     is converted by `pplatex` to:

     ```
     ** Warning in ./demo-multine-efm.tex:
        (Package refcheck) your_equation_label' on input line 17.
     ```
   - [rubber-info](https://github.com/skapfer/rubber) was **successful**

     ```
     WARNING:rubber.cmdline:demo-multine-efm.tex:17: [refcheck] Unused label `eq:your_equation_label'. (page 1)
     ```

   Other tools are

   - [pulp](https://github.com/dmwit/pulp)
   - [texlog-extract](https://ctan.org/pkg/texlog-extract)

---

Demo file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{refcheck}

\begin{document}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod
tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At
vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren,
no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

\begin{equation}
   a=b\label{eq:your_equation_label}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Running `latex` returns a `refcheck` warning with a line number containing a linebreak (`1\n2`):

```
❯ latex log-msg-line-no-with-linebreak.tex
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.19 (TeX Live 2018) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(./log-msg-line-no-with-linebreak.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2018/09/03 v1.4i Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/local/texlive/2018/texmf-dist/tex/latex/refcheck/refcheck.sty)
No file log-msg-line-no-with-linebreak.aux.
Package: `refcheck' v1.9.1 <2013/02/14>
options: showrefs, showcites, msgs, chckunlbld

Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `eq:your_equation_label' on input line 1
2.

[1] (./log-msg-line-no-with-linebreak.aux)

LaTeX Warning: Label(s) may have changed. Rerun to get cross-references right.

 )
Output written on log-msg-line-no-with-linebreak.dvi (1 page, 816 bytes).
Transcript written on log-msg-line-no-with-linebreak.log.
```

With

```
:set efm=%+WPackage\ %s\ Warning:\ %m\ on\ input\ line\ %l
```

reading the log file manually `:cfile log-msg-line-no-with-linebreak.log` generates following warning:

```
|1 warning| Package refcheck Warning: Unused label `eq:your_equation_label' on input line 1
```

As you can see the warning is issued for line number 1 which is incorrect.

---

For the purpose of reference I want to add links to `'efm'` settings for latex or  external tools

- [`:help errorformat-LaTeX`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/quickfix.txt.html#errorformat-LaTeX)
- [$VIMRUNTIME/compiler/tex.vim](https://github.com/vim/vim/blob/master/runtime/compiler/tex.vim#L37-L64)
- [vim-latex compiler/tex.vim](https://github.com/vim-latex/vim-latex/blob/master/compiler/tex.vim#L211)
- vimtex provides settings for

  - [original latex output](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/autoload/vimtex/qf/latexlog.vim)
  - [pplatex output](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/autoload/vimtex/qf/pplatex.vim)
  - [pulp output](https://github.com/lervag/vimtex/blob/master/autoload/vimtex/qf/pulp.vim)